# How to optimize a website for Google Search Generative Experience SGE?

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets

With the latest updates in AI, Google introduced its LLM Model in search called SGE Search Generative Experience, by which they are showing AI-generated content on the top of search results pages.

I believe this will kill a lot of organic traffic to websites.
However, Google is still showing 3 links on the top right corner of the SGE results.

How can we optimize our website for that spot? Are you trying any new tactics for SEO or just following the old-school method of SEO?

[image: screenshot of google sge]

Comment: Search Generative Experience makes it so much harder to treat the dead internet theory with skepticism.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new research paper that talks about how content creators, business owners, and SEO professionals, can increase visibility or can rank on search generative engines, like SGE, Bingchat, perplexity.AI, and similar.

As much as I red, the research paper introduced a new set of strategies, which they call it GEO framework or GEO methodologies, they said GEO or generative engine optimization, can help all content creators, business owners, and SEO professionals to optimize their webpage for generative engine responses, which means, whenever Users interacts with the search generative engine, GEO can help in increasing visibility in those  generative answers.

They introduced total 9 GEO methods, as long as I remember, here are they.

1. authoritative tone method. This method includes modifying the page content and using authoritative writing style.
2. Statistics addition. This method includes adding quantitative or data into the content rather than just providing information.
3. Citations inclusion. This method includes adding credible citations or resources to make the webpage content more credible to impress a generative engines.
4. Quotes. This method includes adding famous quotes to make the webpage content credible similar to the above one.
5. Keyword stuffing: This method includes adding relevant keywords similar to the traditional SEO.
6. Using simple and easy words. This method includes modifying the page content and using simple easy to understand words.
7. Fluency optimization: This method includes how well the text reads or how good the flow of content is.
8. Technical terms: this method includes adding technical terminology but it’s for tech niches only.
9. Using unique words. Now, I don’t quite remember what they mean by this method, but they said adding unique terminologies or vocabulary into the content.
   They also experimented these methods to evaluate whether they work or not.

They call this experiment as GEO bench,, they used 10,000 queries, which contains 80% informational 10% navigational and 10% commercial.

After evaluating these GEO methods they state that it increased up to 40% visibility in generative engine responses.

The most effective method was.

1. Statistic addition. Using quantitative content rather than  Quality content.
2. Authoritative tone. Was also affected
3. Adding citations: Game in the third effective method
4. Adding quotes. Was also a effective.
   Here is the research paper which was contributed with several American universities and Indian university.

https://openreview.net/pdf/d7aef3973d67b5dcaf1b84b76042e9ff6a705d3b.pdf

Comment: Hi Shahnoor, you have managed to make self promotion not look like spam, which is great.  But you should still  tour the help on `self promotion`.

Answer (score 0):

I "**think**" the Old School Method would still prevail. The AI engine is just trying to be helpful and showing resources and most probably the authority sites on the same subject will be shown there.

Featured snippets was already being used earlier and this might be an update kind of method to show AI answers but with citations and references.